# Ransack how to search 'belongs_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ransack

Ransack how to search 'belongs_to'

I want use A.ransack(q) to search attributes

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :b
end 

class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :p
  has_many: a
end
```

How can I use ransack to get p's attributes(like A.ransack(q))

I tried use A.ransack(:b=>{p.eq: 1}), but it didn't work

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#associations

Comment: I want to know how to use on api-only

Comment: I can get result by use A.ransack(b_p_id_eq: 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ransack_alias in model A:

```
ransack_alias :abp, b_p_name

def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
  %w(abp)
end

def self.ransackable_associations(auth_object = nil)
  %w[b]
end
```

In B model:

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
 %w(name)
end
```

In search_form_for:

```
t.search_field :abp_eq
```